# Conan C++ , how to automate building of ALL git tags of a library? preferably in gitlab CICD

Tags: python, c++, gitlab, gitlab-ci, conan

I have a currently working gitlab CICD setup ... which takes my conan recipe , my library repo.. and whichever git tag you hard code.. it will clone that and build the package... and push it to gitlab package manager.. GREAT!

What I am wondering is.. how should I automate this so it looks at the git repo and builds ALL git tags.. so that I can roll back and forth more easily on conan packages.

For reference here is my conan.py

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools


class TwsApiConan(ConanFile):
    name = "twsapi"
    version = "10.17.01"
    license = "IBKR"
    author = "someemail"
    url = "https://github.com/ibkr/tws-api/"
    description = "Built from a mirror of the actual TWS API files in Github"
    topics = ("tws", "interactive brokers")
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    options = {"shared": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False}
    generators = "cmake"

    def source(self):
        self.run("git clone --depth 1 --branch 10.17.01 git@github.com:ibkr/tws-api.git")

        tools.replace_in_file("tws-api/CMakeLists.txt", "         LANGUAGES CXX )",
                              '''         LANGUAGES CXX )
add_compile_options(-std=c++17)''')

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(source_folder="tws-api")
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="tws-api/source/cppclient/client")
        self.copy("*hello.lib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.so", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dylib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.a", dst="lib", keep_path=False)

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["twsapi"]
```

The gitlab CICD routine so far

```
variables: 
  GITHUB_DEPLOY_KEY_BASE64: $GITHUB_DEPLOY_KEY_BASE64

stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.

  stage: build
  image: registry.gitlab.com/jrgemcp-public/gitlab-cicd-docker/build-conan-docker:latest
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - MY_SECRET_DECODED="$(echo $GITHUB_DEPLOY_KEY_BASE64 | base64 -d)"
    - echo "$MY_SECRET_DECODED" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts 2>/dev/null;
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - conan profile new default --detect
    - conan profile update settings.compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 default
    - conan remote add gitlab https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/conan
    - conan user myusername -r gitlab -p ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}
    - conan create . mypackagename/prod
    - conan upload "*" --remote=gitlab --all --confirm
```

Comment: Quick comment: you are using legacy generators like ``cmake``, and legacy imports ``from conans`` (they should be ``from conan``). Said that, I think it is challenging to build all tags, because the build is already associated to a certain commit/tag, and you would need to checkout those other tags first (which might not contain the same conanfile...). I think the easiest is to configure the CI then do a commit/update the desired tags, to fire the build for each one.

Comment: but the conan file is external to the repo I am building (it's a 3rd party), I will look into your suggestions on top of that. thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see. From the Conan side, it is easy, you can leave the ``version`` undefined in the recipe, then pass it in command line, like ``conan create . version@user/channel``, and use ``self.version`` inside the ``source()`` method to checkout the right tag. Knowing which tags to build should probably be defined/computed by the CI, not Conan.

Answer (score 1):

You could [generate your config dynamically](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) in a script. That is to say, you might script getting all the tags/refs you want to build and create a yaml file containing a job for each ref that will checkout the correct ref and build it.

Basic idea in bash:

```bash
for tag in "$(get-all-tags-to-build)"; do
    job_yaml="job ${tag}: {\"script\": \"make build ${tag}\"}"
    echo job_yaml >> generated-config.yml
done
```

The idea being that `make build` is configured to checkout the tag provided as the argument and run the build.

Using that generated config artifact, it will cause the created child pipeline to contain a job for every ref returned by the `get-all-tags-to-build` script (you implement this).